# Creating a PHP header/footer

Tags: php, header, footer

I'm designing a relatively simple site for a friend.  I would like to impliment php so that he can change his header/footer without having to go back through every file.  Problem is, I'm pretty much totally unfamiliar with how php works.  Is there a simplistic way to do this? I've seen a few answers for how to make a php header but they all seem different and I haven't had much success.  I'm not saying they don't work (I probably did it wrong) but the simpler in this case, the better.

Thanks!

Comment: the answes below should help you but a template engine like smarty or twig could save you a lot from these kinds of mess in the future when troubles appear on a bigger scale...its got a relatively simple learning curve with lots of HTML and some variables...

Answer (score 50):

Besides just using `include()` or `include_once()` to include the header and footer, one thing I have found useful is being able to have a custom page title or custom head tags to be included for each page, yet still have the header in a partial include. I usually accomplish this as follows:

In the site pages:

```
<?php

$PageTitle="New Page Title";

function customPageHeader(){?>
  <!--Arbitrary HTML Tags-->
<?php }

include_once('header.php');

//body contents go here

include_once('footer.php');
?>
```

And, in the header.php file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><?= isset($PageTitle) ? $PageTitle : "Default Title"?></title>
    <!-- Additional tags here -->
    <?php if (function_exists('customPageHeader')){
      customPageHeader();
    }?>
  </head>
  <body>
```

Maybe a bit beyond the scope of your original question, but it is useful to allow a bit more flexibility with the include.

Comment: I think it should be **<title><php** instead of **<title><?=**.

Comment: @Adam The `<?=` is equivalent to `<php echo` in cases when [Short Tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) are enabled in PHP.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know!

Comment: I'm unable to edit my comment any longer, but I noticed a typo - it should read `<?php echo`.

Comment: Why is the `customPageHeader` function cut in half by php tags? Anything you put inside the <!--Arbitrary HTML Tags--> section won't be run as php, so why is it inside that php function?

Comment: This helped me to expand my php knowledge

Comment: I fount this answer incredibly useful, thanks

Answer (score 17):

Just create the header.php file, and where you want to use it do:

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>
```

Same with the footer. You don't need php tags in these files if you just have html.

See more about include here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using `include_once()` function in php. Construct a header part in the name of `header.php` and construct the footer part by `footer.php`. Finally include all the content in one file.

For example:

header.php

```
<html>
<title>
<link href="sample.css">
```

footer.php

```
</html>
```

So the final files look like

```
include_once("header.php") 

body content(The body content changes based on the file dynamically)

include_once("footer.php")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for header:
***Important:*** Put the following on your **PHP** pages that you want to include the content.

```
<?php
//at top:
require('header.php'); 
 ?>
 <?php
// at bottom:
require('footer.php');
?>
```

You can also include a navbar globaly just use this instead:

```
 <?php
 // At top:
require('header.php'); 
 ?>
  <?php
// At bottom:
require('footer.php');
 ?>
 <?php
 //Wherever navbar goes:
require('navbar.php'); 
?>
```

In header.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 </head>
 <body>
```

**Do Not close Body or Html tags!**

**Include html here:**

```
 <?php
 //Or more global php here:

 ?>
```

Footer.php:

Code here:

```
<?php
//code

?>
```

Navbar.php:

```
<p> Include html code here</p>
<?php
 //Include Navbar PHP code here
 
?>
```

## Benifits:

- Cleaner main php file (index.php) script.
- Change the header or footer. etc to change it on all pages with the include— Good for alerts on all pages etc...
- Time Saving!
- Faster page loads!
- you can have as many files to include as needed!
- server sided!

Answer (score 1):

> the simpler, the better.

index.php

```
<? 
if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
  $name="index"; 
} else { 
  $name=basename($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 
} 
$file="txt/".$name.".htm"; 
if (is_readable($file)) { 
  include 'header.php';
  readfile($file);
} else { 
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  exit;
} 
?>
```

header.php

```
<a href="index.php">Main page</a><br>
<a href=?about>About</a><br>
<a href=?links>Links</a><br>
<br><br>
```

the actual static html pages stored in the `txt` folder in the `page`.htm format

Comment: This is an interesting method! Would you use this with an htaccess rewrite, or just a more simple www.somesite.com/?about  Can you still have a directory structure inside the txt folder, or does the basename eliminate that?

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer to use a similar approach in conjunction with mod_rewrite, I even had some code I believe. Without mod_rewrite you have to sttick with `?page` way.