# How to add header scripts in a php web page?

Tags: javascript, php, header, include, footer

I have several pages that use the same scripts, for this, i want create a header.php and footer.php file and call them on each page, example.

header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Framework/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Framework/bootstrap/css/bootstraptheme.min.css" />
```

footer.php

```
<script src="../Framework/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Framework/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and my php web page:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    //add header.php
 </head>
 <body>


  //add footer.php
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Use `include` or `require` depending on how you want the page to function if the resource in unavailable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a PHP header/footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054638/creating-a-php-header-footer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
 <head>
    <?php require('header.php'); ?>
 </head>
 <body>


  <?php require('footer.php'); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

As chris85 pointed - you can use include instead of require...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
    <?php include('header.php');?>
 </head>
 <body>
   <?php include('footer.php');?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with jquery as

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <div id="header"></div> //add header.php
 </head>
 <body>


  <div id="footer"></div> //add footer.php
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#header').load('header.html');
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
  });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```