# Is it possible to load an html file with all its functions working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working with two different html files, the index that works as a template where I load other html files such as login panel, shopping cart and, the display(where products are shown) i'm using jQuery the ready method specifically, and it works fine till I try to add a slider with js which works perfectly too when I load the display file directly, the thing is the slider is applied to the display file but when I load it with jQuery it just loads it without any of its functionalities working, i'm trying to be as clear as possibly, i'll share a piece of code, I hope you guys have an idea of what's going on.

```
jQuery:

function loadDisplay(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.body-wrapper").load("display.php")
  });
}

HTML:

  <body onload="loadDisplay()">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="body-wrapper"></div>

JavaScript:

var slideIndex = 0;
function slider(){
    let i;
    let x = document.getElementsByName("bloc-one");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    x[slideIndex -1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(slider,3000);
  }
```

In conclusion the methods and functions work fine till the file is loaded in the index file which is where it stops working.

Comment: If you're using a PHP server, why aren't you leveraging that system to render a complete page? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47041162/5818406

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about it, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html file has `<body>`, but you are loading this file into already existing body. That's first issue. Second, it seems your html file executes `loadDisplay()` when it's loaded, however when it loaded via jquery there is no `onload` event fired.

So, what you need is remove `<body>` and `</body>` tags and at the very end of the file try add this javascript:

```
<script>
loadDisplay()
</script>
```

Comment: Hey! I just tried what you recommended and it works perfectly now, thank you!